# populate NSMutableArray from JSON - Empty =o

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, parsing

I have a problem and I don't understand what is going on. It was working an hour ago and then it stopped working, I don't understand why. :s

Could you please add this JSON in a folder on your localhost and try this piece of code. Then can you tell me if your NSLOG print something better than this :

```
2012-05-16 11:18:21.996 WonderBox[51241:fb03] JSON : (null)


NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/WonderBox/json.txt"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]; 
    NSError *err;
    NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray* )[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];


    NSLog(@"JSON : %@", json);
```

MY JSON :

```
{
    "boxesDetail": [
        {
            "name": "NAME1",
            "number": "12",
            "sexe": "female",
            "topic": "Bien-Ãªtre",
                   },
        {
          "name": "NAME2",
            "number": "33",
             "sexe": "couple",
             "topic": "Bien-Ãªtre",
        },
         {
             "name": "NAME3",
            "number": "43",
             "sexe": "female",
             "topic": "Gastronomie",

        },
             {
          "name": "NAM  E4",
            "number": "33",
             "sexe": "couple",
             "topic": "Adventure",
        },
             {
          "name": "NAME5",
            "number": "102",
             "sexe": "group",
             "topic": "Gastronomie",
        },
             {
          "name": "NAME6",
            "number": "40",
             "sexe": "male",
              "topic": "Sport",
        },
             {
          "name": "NAME7",
            "number": "12",
             "sexe": "male",
             "topic": "Sport",
        }


    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, use http://jsonlint.com/

there shouldn't be a comma at the end of every `topic` key.

```
{
    "boxesDetail": [
        {
            "name": "NAME1",
            "number": "12",
            "sexe": "female",
            "topic": "Bien-Ãªtre" <-- there should be no comma here
        },
...
```

Comment: there is a coma, i found the problem :    "name": "NAM  E4", there is a space and it doesnt work.. but it is weird... WHY ? it should work with space...

Comment: found the answer... it was a tab :// sorry men !